# string.find() aways evaluate to true

Tags: python-3.x

I have a small script that reads a file. After reading a line i'm trying to figure out that the particular line have a especific text in it. For so i do like this

```
for line in file:
    line = line.lower()

    if line.find('my string'):
        print ('found my string in the file')
```

reading the file that line.find aways evaluate to true. When i do like

```
for line in file:
    line = line.lower()

    if 'one big line'.find('my string'):
        print ('found my string in the file')
```

It evaluate to false, as it suppose to do. As i'm realy new to python programming just for what i've shown i just cant think of what i might look for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better idiomatic python to write this as:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.lower()

    if 'my string' in line:
        print ('found my string in the file')
```

rather than using `.find()` if you don't care about the position within the string.

Answer (score 7):

`find` returns a number that's the position of the occurring string inside the search string. If it does not find it, it return `-1`. And every number that's not `0` in python evaluates to `True`. That's why your code always evaluates to `True`.

You need something like:

```
if 'one big line'.find('my string') >= 0:
    print ('found my string in the file')
```

Or, better:

```
idx = 'one big line'.find('my string')
if idx >= 0:
    print ("found 'my string' in position %d" % (idx))
```